# iTextSharp exception: Rebuild failed: Dictionary key R is not a name. at file pointer 9195

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a Windows Service that uses iTextSharp version 5.5.11 to read PDFs out of the DB, pull their text, and upload that text back to the DB for easy searching.

It has worked quite well. But now, it seems every PDF that it opens throws the same exception:

```
iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: Dictionary key R is not a name. at file pointer 9195; Original message: Dictionary key R is not a name. at file pointer 9195 
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, Boolean partialRead, Byte[] ownerPassword, X509Certificate certificate, ICipherParameters certificateKey, Boolean closeSourceOnConstructorError) 
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn)
```

These PDFs are all from different sources, uploaded in different manners at different times - but cannot/will not open via iTextSharp.

This same process has worked for many of other PDFs. And while it appears to be happening to most PDFs now, it's not 100% of them because some still do slip past this piece of code.

Is there something in my code that is causing this? Or do all of these seemingly random PDFs actually have the exact same issue? Or is there something else causing this?  Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** 
Here is the code with the exception; the last line is where the exception occurs:

```
    public string ParseDocumentsFileContents(byte[] PdfFileData, Guid fileId, string fileName)
    {
        if (PdfFileData == null || PdfFileData.Count() <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

        //read the text from each page, and put it all together
        var PageContents = new System.Text.StringBuilder(PdfFileData.Count());
        using (var engine = new Tesseract.TesseractEngine(tessdata_datapath, "eng", Tesseract.EngineMode.Default))
        using (var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileData))
```

And here's an example of a [PDF that resulted in this exception](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYN191cU1IMXlLVVU).  (I realize there is no text in the PDF, but I had to find one that I could share.)

Here are some other examples of PDFs that all resulted in this exception:
[Example #2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYVjQ3WWFTakZBTEk), [Example #3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYOWdmLW1xRkRXWWM), [Example #4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYR0tpeGQ5Y1hxRGM)

**EDIT 2:**
I upgraded to iTextSharp version 5.5.12 and have the same exceptions.  But in both versions, the following PDFs (and others) do NOT result in this exception:  [Does Not Exception Here #1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYTGRrVkFBRGxlcHc) and [Does Not Exception Here #2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5utKmWWQSVYQ2JHN2o5cDRHUmc)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse done.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Anything? I am doing this in a threaded environment, is that causing a problem?

Comment: Sorry, I will not investigate this. I asked for additional information that others require.